# issue in the dd-MM-yyyy format

Tags: java

I am trying to parse date in dd-MM-yyyy and my input is 01-01-2017 it is working fine but when i enter 1-1-2017 or 1-1-17 it is also working but i need only in the format of 01-01-2017 please can any one provide me solution

Thanks in advance

```
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        formatter.setLenient(false);
        String dateInString = "1-01-2013";

        try {

            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to be so strict in your date format?

Comment: Its a requirement in my project where it must be a mandatory format like 01-01-2017 only and it shouldn't accept 1-1-17

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat`, even with `lenient` to `false` (that is the more strict mode) is not enough to get a full strict parsing.

With `DateTimeFormatter` Java 8, you could achieve it :

```
String dateInString = "1-01-2013";

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
try {
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateInString, dtf);
    ...
} catch (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException e) {
    ...
}
```

For information, `ofPattern(String pattern)` uses by default a `ResolverStyle` with the `java.time.format.ResolverStyle.SMART` value.

Comment: Another option is:

LocalDate date = LocalDate.from(
            DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")
                .parse(dateInString)
    );

Answer (score 0):

In addition to davidxxx's solution, you can also use regex to check :)

```
Pattern p =  Pattern.compile("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}");
if (!p.matcher(dateInString).matches()) {
    // bad date format!
}
```

Still, I do not understand why you are being so strict.